# How correctly to initialize some variables?

Tags: variables, go

If I use a variable declaration into `if`, I get an error `undefined: completeTime`

```
    if completeTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, "2016-06-06 18:11:24.617Z"); err != nil {
          return
        }

    fmt.Println(time.Since(completeTime).Seconds())
```

But if I declaration that, I get an error `completeTime declared and not used`

```
    var completeTime time.Time

    if completeTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, "2016-06-06 18:11:24.617Z"); err != nil {
          return
        }

    fmt.Println(time.Since(completeTime).Seconds())
```

Why and how to do it right?

Comment: I have to declare two variables (completeTime and err) for this to work, but it does not look nice

Comment: Go is lexically scoped using blocks: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope. There's nothing wrong with pre-declaring identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a scope problem in your code:

```
if completeTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, "2016-06-06 18:11:24.617Z"); err != nil {
      return
}
fmt.Println(time.Since(completeTime).Seconds())
```

In this sample, `completeTime` is defined only for local scope inside the `if` statement, which means you cannot use it outside it.

```
var completeTime time.Time

if completeTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, "2016-06-06 18:11:24.617Z"); err != nil {
      return
    }

fmt.Println(time.Since(completeTime).Seconds())
```

This one is a bit more tricky. You define a `completeTime` var with the correct scope at the beginning. Then, because of the `:=` operator, you define **another** `completeTime` inside the `if` statement, which masks the first one.

Also, this second variable is not used, that's why you get the error. You can fix this problem by simply assigning `completeTime` and `err` outside the `if`:

```
completeTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, "2016-06-06 18:11:24.617Z")

if err != nil {
    return
}

fmt.Println(time.Since(completeTime).Seconds())
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare it (as you found out) before the if. The scope of the variable in your example is limited to the "if" block. Sorry if it doesn't look nice, but that how it be. Please note your second example requires an additional change (note the change in := on the beginning of your if line):

```
var completeTime time.Time
var err error
if completeTime, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, "2016-06-06 18:11:24.617Z"); err != nil {
      return
}

fmt.Println(time.Since(completeTime).Seconds())
```

Comment: The scope of the variable is limited to `if {} else if {} else {}` so it's perfectly fine to write the `fmt.Println` in the `else` block and you do not have to declare the variable outside of the block.

Comment: I don't disagree, but my answer was directly related to the code OP provided.

Comment: OP provided a version that he discovered worked. He asked for an explanation and how to do it right. It would have been nice to offer both versions as a solution along with an explanation. Maybe merge my answer into yours and I will delete mine?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, variables inside a block are not promoted to the outside of the block. But you can use the declared variables in `else` and `else if` statements.

For example ([on play](https://play.golang.org/p/2bheYhbmrC)):

```
func main() {
    if completeTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, "2016-06-06 18:11:24.617Z"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(time.Since(completeTime).Seconds())
    }
}
```

You can read more about blocks and scopes in the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks).